# The reading of files throughout Numpy library

Tags: python, numpy, file-read

I'm trying to read data in a `text file` by using `Numpy` and these data as shown below:

```
# Student data collected on 17 July 2014
# Researcher: Dr Wicks, University College Newbury

# The following data relate to N = 20 students. It
# has been totally made up and so therefore is 100%
# anonymous.

Subject  Sex    DOB     Height  Weight   BP     VO2max
(ID)     M/F dd/mm/yy     m       kg    mmHg   mL.kg-1.min-1
JW-1     M   19/12/95    1.82    92.4  119/76    39.3
JW-2     M   11/1/96     1.77    80.9  114/73    35.5
JW-3     F    2/10/95    1.68    69.7  124/79    29.1
JW-6     M    6/7/95     1.72    75.5  110/60    45.5
# JW-7   F   28/3/96     1.66    72.4  101/68      -
JW-9     F   11/12/95    1.78    82.1  115/75    32.3
JW-10    F   7/4/96      1.60      -    -/-      30.1
JW-11    M   22/8/95     1.72    77.2  97/63     48.8
JW-12    M   23/5/96     1.83    88.9  105/70    37.7
JW-14    F   12/1/96     1.56    56.3  108/72    26.0
JW-15    F   1/6/96      1.64    65.0  99/67     35.7
JW-16    M   10/9/95     1.63    73.0  131/84    29.9
JW-17    M   17/2/96     1.67    89.8  101/76    40.2
JW-18    M   31/7/96     1.66    75.1   -/-        -
JW-19    F   30/10/95    1.59    67.3  103/69    33.5
JW-22    F   9/3/96      1.70     -    119/80    30.9
JW-23    M   15/5/95     1.97    89.2  124/82      -
JW-24    F   1/12/95     1.66    63.8  100/78      -
JW-25    F   25/10/95    1.63    64.4   -/-      28.0
JW-26    M   17/4/96     1.69      -   121/82    39.
```

I read the `sex` and `Height columns` and I faced no problem throughout my below code:

```
import numpy as np

fname = 'D:\\NumpyTutorial.txt'
datatype1 = np.dtype([('sex','|S1'),('height','f8')])
a = np.loadtxt(fname, dtype=datatype1, skiprows=9, usecols=(1,3))
print(a)
```

But when I tried to read the `Weight column` with this code below:

```
import numpy as np

fname = 'D:\\NumpyTutorial.txt'
datatype1 = np.dtype([('sex','|S1'),('height','f8'),('Weight','f8')])
a = np.loadtxt(fname, dtype=datatype1, skiprows=9, usecols=(1,3,4))
print(a)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'.
```

1- How could I deal with this `sign(-)`.How can I read this column?.

2- For `sex column` I used `'|S1'` and for `height` used `'f8'`, what is the `syntax` for `Subject, BOD and BP columns` until to read them?.

3 - How could I display everything in this file?

Comment: `genfromtxt` handles missing values better

Comment: I'll check it out @hpaulj

Comment: @hpaulj it gave me a list full of (b'J', nan)

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use Pandas?

Comment: @BallpointBen I'm learning dear sir. I didn't take Pandas Yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

You can use `np.genfromtxt` with its `missing_values` and `filling_values` arguments.  I made some dummy data of the following form in `data.txt`, which has an entry missing.

```
ID      Value
0       10
1       58
2       -
3       27
```

I then loaded this data using `np.genfromtxt` as shown in the following code block.  Note that this will simply retrieve the data using the desired format -- you will need to do post-processing on the data yourself to make sure you're not using invalid or missing entries inappropriately.

In this example case, I set the filled-in values from the missing entries to `-1` because I expected all my values to be positive.  Another easy choice of `filling_values` for data processing's sake would be `np.nan`.

```
import numpy as np

fname = './data.txt'
data = np.genfromtxt(fname, skip_header=1, \
        missing_values='-', filling_values=-1.) 

print(data)


###  Output:
###    [[ 0. 10.]
###     [ 1. 58.]
###     [ 2. -1.]
###     [ 3. 27.]]
```

You should be able to use the same technique for your weight and VO2max columns.  I'm not sure how to treat the BP column due to its formatting -- that choice is up to you, but the technique is the same.

Answer (score 0):

With a copy-n-paste of your text to a file, I got this download.  I had to play with `skip_header`.  I'd have liked to use `names=True`, but column header line is followed by a units line, which I can't (readily) skip.

```
In [60]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack57367863.csv', dtype=None, skip_header=8, encoding=None)                 
In [61]: data                                                                                                
Out[61]: 
array([('JW-1', 'M', '19/12/95', 1.82, '92.4', '119/76', '39.3'),
       ('JW-2', 'M', '11/1/96', 1.77, '80.9', '114/73', '35.5'),
       ('JW-3', 'F', '2/10/95', 1.68, '69.7', '124/79', '29.1'),
       ...
       ('JW-26', 'M', '17/4/96', 1.69, '-', '121/82', '39.')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<U1'), ('f2', '<U8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<U4'), ('f5', '<U6'), ('f6', '<U4')])
```

Unfortunately only one column was loaded as float; the '-' kept the other numeric column from loading as numbers.

I like to use the automatic dtype, but let's try an explicit one:

```
In [62]: dt=[('subject', 'U10'),('sex','U2'),('dob','U10'),('height','f'),('weight','f'),('bp','U10'),('vo2','f')]                                                                                                
In [63]: np.dtype(dt)                                                                                        
Out[63]: dtype([('subject', '<U10'), ('sex', '<U2'), ('dob', '<U10'), ('height', '<f4'), ('weight', '<f4'), ('bp', '<U10'), ('vo2', '<f4')])
In [64]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack57367863.csv', dtype=dt, 
    skip_header=8, encoding=None)                   
In [65]: data                                                                                                
Out[65]: 
array([('JW-1', 'M', '19/12/95', 1.82, 92.4, '119/76', 39.3),
       ('JW-2', 'M', '11/1/96', 1.77, 80.9, '114/73', 35.5),
       ('JW-3', 'F', '2/10/95', 1.68, 69.7, '124/79', 29.1),
       ('JW-6', 'M', '6/7/95', 1.72, 75.5, '110/60', 45.5),
       ('JW-9', 'F', '11/12/95', 1.78, 82.1, '115/75', 32.3),
       ('JW-10', 'F', '7/4/96', 1.6 ,  nan, '-/-', 30.1),
       ('JW-11', 'M', '22/8/95', 1.72, 77.2, '97/63', 48.8),
       ('JW-12', 'M', '23/5/96', 1.83, 88.9, '105/70', 37.7),
       ('JW-14', 'F', '12/1/96', 1.56, 56.3, '108/72', 26. ),
       ('JW-15', 'F', '1/6/96', 1.64, 65. , '99/67', 35.7),
       ('JW-16', 'M', '10/9/95', 1.63, 73. , '131/84', 29.9),
       ('JW-17', 'M', '17/2/96', 1.67, 89.8, '101/76', 40.2),
       ('JW-18', 'M', '31/7/96', 1.66, 75.1, '-/-',  nan),
       ('JW-19', 'F', '30/10/95', 1.59, 67.3, '103/69', 33.5),
       ('JW-22', 'F', '9/3/96', 1.7 ,  nan, '119/80', 30.9),
       ('JW-23', 'M', '15/5/95', 1.97, 89.2, '124/82',  nan),
       ('JW-24', 'F', '1/12/95', 1.66, 63.8, '100/78',  nan),
       ('JW-25', 'F', '25/10/95', 1.63, 64.4, '-/-', 28. ),
       ('JW-26', 'M', '17/4/96', 1.69,  nan, '121/82', 39. )],
      dtype=[('subject', '<U10'), ('sex', '<U2'), ('dob', '<U10'), 
          ('height', '<f4'), ('weight', '<f4'), ('bp', '<U10'), ('vo2', '<f4')])
```

Fields are accessed by name:

```
In [66]: data['height']                                                                                      
Out[66]: 
array([1.82, 1.77, 1.68, 1.72, 1.78, 1.6 , 1.72, 1.83, 1.56, 1.64, 1.63,
       1.67, 1.66, 1.59, 1.7 , 1.97, 1.66, 1.63, 1.69], dtype=float32)
In [67]: data['weight']                                                                                      
Out[67]: 
array([92.4, 80.9, 69.7, 75.5, 82.1,  nan, 77.2, 88.9, 56.3, 65. , 73. ,
       89.8, 75.1, 67.3,  nan, 89.2, 63.8, 64.4,  nan], dtype=float32)
```

The '-' is rendered as `np.nan`.

With `missing_values` parameter I get `dtype=None` working:

```
In [78]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack57367863.csv', dtype=None, 
    skip_header=8, encoding=None, missing_values='-')                                                                                                 
In [79]: data                                                                                                
Out[79]: 
array([('JW-1', 'M', '19/12/95', 1.82, 92.4, '119/76', 39.3),
       ('JW-2', 'M', '11/1/96', 1.77, 80.9, '114/73', 35.5),
       ('JW-3', 'F', '2/10/95', 1.68, 69.7, '124/79', 29.1),
       ('JW-6', 'M', '6/7/95', 1.72, 75.5, '110/60', 45.5),
       ('JW-9', 'F', '11/12/95', 1.78, 82.1, '115/75', 32.3),
       ('JW-10', 'F', '7/4/96', 1.6 ,  nan, '-/-', 30.1),
       ('JW-11', 'M', '22/8/95', 1.72, 77.2, '97/63', 48.8),
       ...
       ('JW-26', 'M', '17/4/96', 1.69,  nan, '121/82', 39. )],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<U1'), ('f2', '<U8'), ('f3', '<f8'), 
           ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<U6'), ('f6', '<f8')])
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help sir. Thank you so much.